# Using options in lsqcurvefit

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, least-squares, levenberg-marquardt

I want to use Levenberg Marquardt Algorithm in the [`lsqcurvefit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) command. I've done the following :

```
options = optimset('LevenbergMarquardt','on');
x = lsqcurvefit(@myfun,x0,xdata,ydata,options);
```

I get the following error:

> `??? Error using ==> optim\private\lsqncommon
>
>   LSQCURVEFIT only accepts inputs of data type double.`
>
> Error in ==> lsqcurvefit at        149
>   [x,Resnorm,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA,JACOB] = ...

How do I overcome this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/toolbox/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) for the function `lsqcurvefit`. You are using the function wrong. To pass the struct `options` you should use the 7-argument version and pass the struct as the last 7th argument:

```
x = lsqcurvefit(@myfun,x0,xdata,ydata,lb,ub,options);
```

This means that you also need to define `lb` and `ub` as the 5th and 6th argument. These are the lower and upper bounds for the design variable in `x`.

But you can also pass empty matrices if no bounds exist:

```
x = lsqcurvefit(@myfun,x0,xdata,ydata,[],[],options);
```